# Why does my VB.NET Snake game freeze when I hold a key down?

Tags: vb.net, timer, freeze, keydown

I'm trying to make the classic Snake game in VB.NET, but if I hold a key (any key) during the game, after a few seconds the game freezes until I release the key. I've tried lots to fix this, but nothing works, maybe because I don't understand the problem.

I'm assuming that when I hold down a key, the Form1_KeyDown function gets called, and when, after a few seconds, the key goes into "I'm being held down" mode, that function is constantly called, so the timers don't get a chance to update. But like I said, I'm probably wrong.

Any help at all would be appreciated, I've been struggling with this for a while. I think this is all the necessary code, please let me know if it isn't.

Code for key down event:

```
 Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

    ' Sorts out all the key presses: movement, resetting, pausing

    ' Change direction, unless the player tries to travel backwards into themself
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case upKey
            If previousDirection <> "D" Then
                nextDirection = "U"
            End If
        Case leftKey
            If previousDirection <> "R" Then
                nextDirection = "L"
            End If
        Case rightKey
            If previousDirection <> "L" Then
                nextDirection = "R"
            End If
        Case downKey
            If previousDirection <> "U" Then
                nextDirection = "D"
            End If
        Case resetKey
            resetGame()
        Case pauseKey
            paused = Not paused
            If paused Then
                lblPaused.Visible = True
                tmrTime.Stop()
                tmrFruit.Stop()
                tmrMove.Stop()
            Else
                lblPaused.Visible = False
                tmrTime.Start()
                tmrFruit.Start()
                tmrMove.Start()
            End If
    End Select

End Sub
```

Code for the timer that updates/moves the snake (I'm aware this is really inefficient):

```
 Private Sub tmrMove_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrMove.Tick

    ' Adds a new head in direction of travel, and removes the tail, giving the illusion of snake movement

    Dim head As Object = bodyParts(bodyParts.Count - 1)
    Dim tail As Object = bodyParts(0)
    Dim newHead As Object

    head.Text = ""

    ' Add new head
    Select Case nextDirection

        Case "R"
            ' If snake goes out of bounds
            If head.Tag(0) + 1 >= numberOfColumns Then
                newHead = grid(0, head.Tag(1))
                If newHead.BackColor = snakeColor Then
                    killSnake()
                End If
            Else
                ' If snake overlaps itself
                If bodyParts.Contains(grid(head.Tag(0) + 1, head.Tag(1))) Then
                    killSnake()
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    ' If snake is fine
                    newHead = grid(head.Tag(0) + 1, head.Tag(1))
                End If
            End If

            ' If fruit taken
            If newHead.BackColor = fruitColor Then
                eatFruit(newHead, tail)
            End If

        Case "L"
            If head.Tag(0) - 1 < 0 Then
                newHead = grid(numberOfColumns - 1, head.Tag(1))
                If newHead.BackColor = snakeColor Then
                    killSnake()
                End If
            Else
                If bodyParts.Contains(grid(head.Tag(0) - 1, head.Tag(1))) Then
                    killSnake()
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    newHead = grid(head.Tag(0) - 1, head.Tag(1))
                End If
            End If

            If newHead.BackColor = fruitColor Then
                eatFruit(newHead, tail)
            End If

        Case "U"
            If head.Tag(1) - 1 < 0 Then
                newHead = grid(head.Tag(0), numberOfRows - 1)
                If newHead.BackColor = snakeColor Then
                    killSnake()
                End If
            Else
                If bodyParts.Contains(grid(head.Tag(0), head.Tag(1) - 1)) Then
                    killSnake()
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    newHead = grid(head.Tag(0), head.Tag(1) - 1)
                End If
            End If

            If newHead.BackColor = fruitColor Then
                eatFruit(newHead, tail)
            End If

        Case "D"
            If head.Tag(1) + 1 >= numberOfRows Then
                newHead = grid(head.Tag(0), 0)
            Else
                If bodyParts.Contains(grid(head.Tag(0), head.Tag(1) + 1)) Then
                    killSnake()
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    newHead = grid(head.Tag(0), head.Tag(1) + 1)
                End If
            End If

            If newHead.BackColor = fruitColor Then
                eatFruit(newHead, tail)
            End If

        Case Else
            newHead = grid(head.Tag(0), head.Tag(1))

    End Select

    bodyParts.Add(newHead)
    newHead.BackColor = snakeColor
    newHead.Font = headFont
    newHead.Text = headText

    ' Remove tail
    tail.BackColor = gridColor
    bodyParts.RemoveAt(0)

    previousDirection = nextDirection

End Sub
```

Comment: That won't prevent the system from raising that event continuously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm assuming that when I hold down a key, the Form1_KeyDown function gets called, and when, after a few seconds, the key goes into "I'm being held down" mode, that function is constantly called, so the timers don't get a chance to update. But like I said, I'm probably wrong.

In fact, you are right.

In Windows you'll get a `WM_KEYDOWN` message as soon as the key is pressed, and then, after a certain interval, you'll be getting lots of `WM_KEYDOWN` messages with another certain interval between them.

You can find these intervals if you go to Control Panel - Keyboard.

<s>The easiest way of fixing it is adding a call to `DoEvents` in the end of the key handler.</s>

<s>Try removing the keydown handler completely. Instead, figure `nextDirection` in the beginnig of `tmrMove_Tick` by examining [`Keyboard.IsKeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.iskeydown.aspx).</s>

Try removing the keydown handler completely. Instead, figure `nextDirection` in the beginning of `tmrMove_Tick` by examining `GetAsyncKeyState`, which you can declare as follows:

```
Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" Alias "GetAsyncKeyState" (ByVal vKey As Keys) As Short

Private Shared Function IsKeyDown(ByVal Key As Keys) As Boolean
    Return (GetAsyncKeyState(Key) And &H8000S) = &H8000S
End Function
```

Comment: You're right, if I change the delay until Windows counts it as being held, it takes longer for Snake to freeze. So thank you, I'm sure of the problem now.

Comment: I tried adding Application.DoEvents() to the end of the event handler, and then to start, but neither worked.

Comment: There's no Keyboard.IsKeyDown method/event/Idon'tknowthename. Nor is there System.Windows.Input. I tried Imports System.Windows.Input, but that didn't work either. I'm pretty new for VB, as you can probably gather, so I'm sort of meddling with stuff I don't understand when it comes to importing things. But if there was a simple way to get the state of a key, that would be perfect.

Comment: @SiliconCelery There's a [link in the answer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.iskeydown.aspx), which takes you to the docs page which tells you it's in PresentationCore.dll. You have to add two references to the project, to `System.Windows.Presentation` (that you do yourself) and to `WindowsBase` (that the compiler tells you to do). Anyway, you don't have to do that because that stuff is for WPF and does not work in a Windows Forms app. See another edit.

Comment: That last comment went completely over my head. And I also don't understand the VK_ constants, what they are, what they do. I tried putting all the direction-changing code in the tmrMove_Tick function, and used "If GetAsyncKeyState(upKey) Then", for example, but there was still the problem of the game freezing. =[ edit: "Dim upKey As Keys = Keys.Up" is in the code as well.

Comment: @SiliconCelery `VK_` constants are mere integer constants. It happened so their values are equal to corresponding `Keys` members so you can use those. Don't just do `If GetAsyncKeyState(upKey) Then`, instead have a function (see another edit). As for the freezing, have you completely removed the keydown handler?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying the keyup event instead. It won't spam like the keypress nor keydown events

Comment: Still exactly the same problem, I'm afraid.

Comment: did you stop using the keydown event? Keyup only fires once per keypress

Comment: I changed all the keyDown's to keyUp's, and although the movement seemed smoother, it still froze after a few seconds of holding a key down.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct with the problem being with the key repeating. I have in the past used a variable to hold the previous keystate and exit the keypressed event if it is the same. I am reseting this with a timer that should get you enough of a delay.

```
If oldKeyData = e.KeyCode Then
    e.Handled = True
    Exit Sub
End If

oldKeyData = e.KeyCode
tmrKeyReset.Enabled = True
```

Edit: @SpectralGhosts answer will work if you want to move with individual key presses.

Comment: Forgive me for being slow, but what does the timer do? Does that need code?

Comment: The timer resets oldKeyData so that it will process the KeyCode again. It is slowing down the amount of KeyDowns you are processing without effecting the computer's global settings.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Isn't the problem that although this idea exits the function, the function is still being called straight away afterwards, no matter what else I do, and not giving the timer a chance to do anything?

Comment: That explains why I had an Application.DoEvents between the e.Handled = true and the Exit Sub. It won't stop the function from being called, just from it processing your logic

Comment: It still doesn't work, even with the Application.DoEvents in. I'm starting to think there's something else wrong with my code, because a lot of the solutions seem like they should work.

Comment: Have you tried @GSerg 's answer about polling for keystate in your timer? That might be your answer.