# check when first pressed a key in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I want to maake an object change direction when I press an arrow key and stop when I stop pressing the key. However, when I press one key, and then press the other one, it just goes left because it changes the direction back all the time. Here is the code for keyDown:

```
Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Right
            direction = 1
        Case Keys.Left
            direction = -1
End Select
```

Code for keyUp:

```
Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Right
            If direction = 1 Then
                direction = 0
            End If
        Case Keys.Left
            If direction = -1 Then
                direction = 0
            End If
    End Select
```

Is there any way to check when was the last key pressed?

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626110/why-does-my-vb-net-snake-game-freeze-when-i-hold-a-key-down

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint on the first line of the key up code to see what happens when you release the key - Also it would be helpful to show more code - all the subs relating to key handling - including the definitions - e.g. Private sub keyDown(....) etc